# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 and file upload more than 10 MB

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-rest, embedded-tomcat-8

To my Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 `application.properties` I have added the following lines:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB 
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

but when I try to upload to my RestController the 21MB file it fails with the following exception:

```
Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (21112803) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
```

I run my application on Embedded Tomcat packaged with Spring Boot.

How to properly configure my application in order to allow file upload up to 100MB?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration), and in [its appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties), the correct  properties are `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size`.

Comment: If the underlying webserver is Tomcat, you must also set this:    

server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size=100MB

Answer (score 1):

For SpringBoot 1.5.7 till or before 2.1.2 the property need to set in application.properties file are:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Also make sure you have application.properties file in "resources" folder. In case you are not sure with the size then "-1" is the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1000MB


spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

Above both the way not working in my version(1.3.4) also,

So that i used following way and it's working,

```
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.max-file-size=100MB
multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spring boot version 2.4.3 and after this version use this

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1 spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1`